# How can I say "one half" in French?

Tags: nombres

How can I say "one half" (1/2) in French? I just know that it will "une" something.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary before you asked the question? [For example](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/one%20half). What did you find and be specific about why it doesn't suit your needs. [Please visit the help centre for more](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's "un demi" or "une demie" with specific rules about hyphen and agreement when it's followed by a noun or an adjective (une demi-heure, des demi-frères, demi-fins). Check this: http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-demi-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-demie-%C2%BB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trois expressions possibles pour traduire l'idée de moitié.

- **demi**

0.5 : un demi.
1.5 : un et demi.

> Une **demi**-page
>   Une heure **et demie** (90 minutes)

- **La moitié**

La moitié de quelque chose

> Veux-tu une part?
>   - J'**en** prendrais bien **la moitié**.

- **mi**

> Nous sommes à **mi-chemin**.
>   Cette table m'arrive à **mi-hauteur**.

Comment: La moitié ou une moitié. C'est logique mais pour un apprenant peut-être pas trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Une demie.

For example : "Je voudrais **une demie** baguette".

Au masculin ce serait **un demi**.

You can also say **la moitié** : "J'en prendrai la moitié".

*Une moitié* is exclusively feminine.

Comment: Pour info, *moitié* s'écrit sans *e*. Je corrige.

Comment: Et attention à la règle avec *demi*. *Une demi-baguette* mais *une baguette et demie*.

Comment: ...ou un pain de mie. Désolé pour le jeu de mots...

Comment: @LaurentS. Un demi-pain de mie peint de My.